# Integrating QGIS into ExpressJS web application as TIFF image viewer

Tags: geotiff-tiff, qgis-web-client

I am working on an Express based application which is primarily intended to Object detection from TIFF images. As of now, I am using OpenSeaDragon to load the TIFF images into the application but it is too slow for large size images i.e ~2-3GB.

In the meantime, while exploring on the Internet, I came to know that QGIS can fulfill my requirements, but unfortunately I am not able to find a way how.

How can I do this?